# Frame buffer object support

Tags: opengl, fbo

Do most OpenGL 2.0 and 2.1 graphics cards that still are in use support frame buffer objects (through the GL_ARB_framebuffer_object or GL_EXT_framebuffer_object extensions)?

Comment: Even if they don't, they provide equivalents. However, 3.0 was introduced in nv 9xxx series, which was years ago.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: nVIDIA doesn't worry me, but some of our customers have fairly old Intel graphics cards.

Comment: Did you take a look at Angle lib ? it provides Opengl ES over DirectX, if may help you on old Intel drivers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experience, they do.

Among nVidia, GPUs at least as far back as the GeForce FX 5xxx (which support OpenGL 2.0) have FBO support, and I suspect even older cards do.

Among ATI GPUs old enough to only support OpenGL 2.0, I have seen such GPUs as the HD 2400 and the X1300, and they all support FBOs.

Among Intel GPUs, I think that it is mainly the HD Graphics families that have OpenGL 2.0 support at all, and all the HD Graphics GPUs I've seen have FBO support. I have also seen some other GPUs with 2.0 and FBO support, including some versions of the 965, and something called the "Eaglelake". I'm not sure why only some 965s support OpenGL 2.0, though. It could be a driver issue.

I have, on the other hand, not yet found any 2.0-compatible GPUs that do *not* support FBOs.

I hope this purely empirical answer helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes. My Intel GMA 950's Windows 7 driver (at least) unofficially exposes OpenGL 2.0 features and frame buffer objects are supported through the EXT_framebuffer_object extension.